# how to get row index of a row on second page of grid view

Tags: c#, .net, gridview, checkbox

I have a grid view which stores cities with paging and has 10 cities per page.

How can I get the row index of any row on the second page in asp.net? The name of the grid view is **gdvCities**.

I have tried the following:

```
CheckBox chkcity = (CheckBox)sender;
GridViewRow gdvrow = (GridViewRow)chkcity.NamingContainer;
int rowindex = gdvrow.RowIndex;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int rowindex = (gdvrow.RowIndex * gdvCities.PageIndex+1)
```

gdvrow.PageIndex will give you the index of page, by default on first page, page index is 0. so add 1 to get exact value

Comment: protected void Checked_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            CheckBox chkcity = (CheckBox)sender;
            GridViewRow gdvrow = (GridViewRow)chkcity.NamingContainer;
            //int rowindex = gdvrow.RowIndex % gdvCities.PageSize;
            int rowindex = (gdvrow.RowIndex * gdvrow.PageIndex + 1));   its giving error that PageIndex is not avialble for gdvrow.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below code snippet.

```
int rowindex = (gdvrow.RowIndex == 0 ? (gdvCities.PageIndex + 1) : (gdvrow.RowIndex * gdvCities.PageIndex + 1));
```

Comment: I have updated above code snippet. Can you please check this once again? Let me know if any concern.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late post, but in case anyone was wondering, this was my solution:

```
CheckBox chkcity = (CheckBox)sender;
GridViewRow gdvrow = (GridViewRow)chkcity.NamingContainer;
int rowindex = gdvrow.RowIndex;

var pagesize = this.GridView1.PageSize;
var pageindex = this.GridView1.PageIndex;
//basically, you want to take the pagesize multiplied by the page index, then subtract that from the rowIndex
paginatedRowIndex = rowindex - (pagesize * pageindex);
```

the paginatedRowIndex variable will be the row index you want to use when utilizing a paginated gridview.

-Sahan

Answer (score 0):

(GridView1.PageSize * GridView1.PageIndex) + e.row.rowIndex